# Change select background colour when a non disabled option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

looking for a way to change the colour of a select box if one of the disabled options is not selected.

So this is the example drop down:

```
    <select class="selectoption" name="desc[]">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select option...</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    </select>
```

How can i change the background colour of this select box, if the disbaled option is not selected.

So the back ground colour is #333 currently, once a user selects an option it is changed to another colour.

i already am doing something similiar using checkboxes. But i am able to use the

```
checkbox:checked
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no problem in using javascript, you can check for the selected option that has a value.

HTML:

```
<select id="sel1" class="selectoption" name="desc[]">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select option...</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("sel1").onchange = function() {
    if(this.value != null && this.value != undefined)
    {
        this.className = "myclass";
    }
};
```

CSS:

```
select.myclass
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AWMaa/